# How do I deserialize a JSON array that contains only values?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm getting this result from a web function.

```
["767,20150221122715,121053103,14573465,1,7,302",
"767,20150221122756,121053165,14573375,1,0,302",
"767,20150221122840,121053498,14572841,1,12,124"]
```

Usually Json have PropertyName: Value
But this have an array of strings, and each string have the values separated by comma. I know what each value position mean.

I try using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` but couldn't make it work.

```
string deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
//and
List<string> deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
```

I can parse the string doing a split, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way.

Comment: Can you [edit] the title of your question to something that actually has meaning? *This is a JSON string* has no meaning, and it will be absolutely irrelevant to anyone who finds it in a search result in the future. The title should explain the problem you're having or the question you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: This is a comment :)

Comment: @leppie: My point exactly. It certainly isn't a question.

Comment: The JSON result you are getting is a JSON array which is perfectly legal, I would recommend you to to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192357/deserializing-json-object-array-with-json-net

Comment: I change it for "Is this a correct Json string?"

Comment: @JasonZ thanks for the suggestion, As you saw for my first question i wasnt sure that was an Json string. But now you question make it easy to find how to solve it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You're welcome!  A good site to use to test out whether you have a valid JSON string or not is http://www.jslint.com/.

Comment: Now with the new title, it really makes it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18192564/105104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, according to to http://json.org/, it is a valid JSON value (an array of string).

To deserialize it according to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192357/deserializing-json-object-array-with-json-net) you should use
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);`
to convert it

Comment: Your first assumption was that the JSON result was invaldi which didn't help your search for an answer, I suggest you go upvote the people in the linked SO question which would help people in the future

Comment: @Thomas please create the question related to this, or better yet search google, if you are using `JsonConvert` this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18948852/105104) should be what you search for.

Answer (score 2):

The generic parameter to the `DeserializeObject<T>()` method is the type you want the deserializer to deserialize to. Your json string represents an array of strings so you should be deserializing to a collection of strings (typically `List<string>`).

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

However, it isn't necessary to specify the type.  There is a non-generic overload that returns `object`. It will (in this case) return an instance of a `JArray` with the appropriate values.

```
object values = JsonConvert.Deserialize(json);
```

Though, it would be better to return a more specific type if possible.  To keep it more generalized, you can use `JToken` for the generic type or even more specifically, `JArray`.

```
var values = JsonConvert.Deserialize<JToken>(json); // good
var values = JsonConvert.Deserialize<JArray>(json); // better in this case
```