# Pass an array from C# to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, vsto, office-addins, com-interop

We have a JavaScript Office add-in. We are making an installable and executable add-in on top of it by VSTO and WebView2.

I just realize that it's not obvious to pass an array value from C# to JavaScript. For instance, on the side of C#, I have the following code:

```
public object test()
{
    int[,] xx = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };
    return xx;
}
```

In JavaScript, I have

```
test () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let result = await window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.control.test();
            console.log(result)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
            resolve(result)
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Then, in the console of JavaScript, it shows `Array(0)` and `[]`. If I pass a string value from C# to JavaScript, it works well.

Does anyone know how to pass an array from C# to JavaScript?

Comment: Write the script on the back end an post it.  There's not enough info to provide an example.  `<% JavaScriptCode %>`.  Have you tried converting to JSON?

Comment: I believe this is one of the use cases `dynamic` was introduced for. But @AlexT. is right. More information is needed. I will note however that JavaScript does not support multi-dimensional arrays. It supports jagged arrays. Use a jagged array on the C# side as well if you're interoperating with the language that has no concept of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: you can return Json object instead of returning object. the following link may help you. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must serialize objects and arrays to any format that suits your needs. But I think for JavaScript the most suitable format would be a JSON string, so you could get a ready made object in JavaScript. See [Serialize c# array of strings to JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948053/serialize-c-sharp-array-of-strings-to-json-array) for more information.

Comment: Finally, i use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on the side of C#, and `JSON.parse` on the side of JavaScript.